# Bind array to IN() in prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement, adodb

I have following code, which should update `update_this` column in my database for list of IDs stored in array:

```
// id NUMBER
// update_this CHAR(1 CHAR)

$sql = '
    UPDATE my_table
    SET update_this = :update_this
    WHERE id IN(:ids)
';

$binds = array(
    'update_this' => '1',
    'ids' => implode(',', $ids)
);

$db->Execute($sql, $binds);
```

But when I run this, I end with message "*ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column*". I tried to bind `ids` as array with `'ids' => $ids`, but then I failed with "*ORA-01008: not all variables bound*". What is the proper way how to bind array into `IN()`?

Comment: Can you show us what `$ids` is? How many values are in there?

Comment: `WHERE id IN(' . implode(',',array_fill(0, count($ids),'?')) . ')`

Comment: `$ids` is list of numeric IDs (1,2,3 ... 999,1000), exactly 1000 (Oracle limitation for static IN()). I know I can put it directly into query, but it's little bit agains prepared statement, I am looking for solution with PS.

Answer (score 0):

@user2943773 clearly misunderstood my comment:

```
$ids = array(1,5,123,1000,5236);

$sql = '
    UPDATE my_table
    SET update_this = ?
    WHERE id IN(' . implode(',',array_fill(0, count($ids),'?')) . ')
';

$binds = array('1') + $ids;

$db->Execute($sql, $binds);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
$ids = array( '1', '5', '123', '1000', '5236');
$ids = array_combine(range(2, count($ids)+1), $ids);
$ids[1] = 1;  // For update_this
$inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$sql =  'UPDATE my_table
        SET update_this = ?
        WHERE id IN('.$inQuery.')';
$db->Execute($sql, $ids);
```

Comment: Well, example IDs in my comment were only example, I have in my array random IDs like 1, 5, 123, 1000, 5236...

Comment: better delete your duplicated answer.